# How to match a particular string using regex?

Tags: regex

Hi i have string like below,

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:  <------------------------  this is one cluster
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ
    server: https://api.someaddress 
name: https://api.anotheraddress
- second_cluster:  <------------------------  this is second cluster
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1
    server: https://api.someaddress
name: https://api.
contexts:
- context:  <------------------------  this is one context
    cluster: https://api.another1address
    namespace: name1           
    user: user1
 name: somename
- another_context:  <------------------------  this is second context
    cluster: https://api.anotheraddress
    namespace: esm2
    user: admin
name: somename1
current-context: some-context
kind: somekind
preferences: {}
users:
- name: user-admin
    user:
        token: eyJhb
```

how can i check if the there is more than one cluster under clusters and more than one context under contexts using regex.

i have tried something like below

```
var matchServer = new RegExp(/- cluster:\n[A-Za-z0-9\- :]*\n[ ]+server: ([A-Za-z:.//]*)/, "gi").exec(s);
const namespace = s.match(/contexts:\n- context:\n[A-Za-z0-9\- :.//]*\n[ ]+namespace: ([A-Za-z0-9]*)/i);
```

but this gives server and namespace also only one occurrence is returned.

i want to get the number of matched string "cluster" under clusters and context under contexts.

could someone help me with this. i am new to programming. thanks.

**what i have tried?**

i have tried regex to match "context" "another_context" under contexts. but it matches only "context"

contexts:\n-.*context:+

could someone help me understand why it doesnt match the another_context string

**updated question:**

with the regex

const matchServer = result.match(/- [a-z_]*cluster:[A-Za-z0-9- :\n]*[ ]+server: ([A-Za-z0-9:.//]*)/gi);

this returns null for below string although there is server under cluster.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 
LS0tLS1CRUd
    server: https://api.sandbox1.lab.fi.eu.ericsson.se
  name: https://api.sandbox1.lab.fi.eu.ericsson.se
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: https://api.sandbox1.lab.fi.eu.ericsson.se
    namespace: esm1
    user: esm-esm1-ci-namespace-admin
  name: esm-context
current-context: esm-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: esm-esm1-ci-namespace-admin
  user:
    token: 
eyJhbGc
```

why doesnt the above regex work for this string. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: While not impossible, I don't think regex is the right tool for what you want to do. It looks like you're trying to parse YAML, so you probably should use a YAML parser.

Comment: could you please provide a solution with an outline how it can be done. i am new to programming so would be grateful if you could add some ideas in the solution with which i could try. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var s = `apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:  
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ
    server: https://api.someaddress1
name: https://api.anotheraddress
- second_cluster:  
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1
    server: https://api.someaddress2
name: https://api.
contexts:
- context:  
    cluster: https://api.another1address
    namespace: name1           
    user: user1
 name: somename
- another_context: 
    cluster: https://api.anotheraddress
    namespace: esm2
    user: admin
name: somename1
current-context: some-context
kind: somekind
preferences: {}
users:
- name: user-admin
    user:
        token: eyJhb`;
 var matchServer = s.match(/- [a-z_]*cluster:/gi)
 var matchNamespace = s.match(/- [a-z_]*context:/gi)
 document.write(matchServer.length + ' servers <br/>')
 for(i=0;i<matchServer.length;i++)
  document.write(matchServer[i] + '<br/>')
 document.write(matchNamespace.length + ' namespaces <br/>')
 for(i=0;i<matchNamespace.length;i++)
  document.write(matchNamespace[i] + '<br/>')
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xencj8qg/)

Comment: thanks a lot. but would be nice to find the number of cluster and context instead of server and namespaces. meaning it should match "cluster", "second_cluster" and return 2 matches. and should match "context" "another_context" and should return 2 matches

Comment: is that what you want [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xencj8qg/) ?

Comment: I'll let you improve this solution...

Comment: for one string the regex for matchServer doesnt work. i have updated question with the string. in the updated question section of my question. please take a look. thanks.

Comment: /[a-z_ ]*cluster:/gi

Comment: i want to get the server too.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a solution with a [YAML parser](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) - provided that it actually is YAML, because the last part (`users`) isn't valid YAML. Also some indentation wasn't right. I assume it has been modified to not leak sensitive information.

**Update:** Oh, I see this is a kubernetes config file. So it really is YAML then.

https://jsfiddle.net/1Lpsk740/ (with `document.write` instead of `console.log`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-yaml/4.1.0/js-yaml.js"></script>
<script>
var input = `apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:  
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ
    server: https://api.someaddress1
    name: https://api.anotheraddress
- second_cluster:  
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1
    server: https://api.someaddress2
    name: https://api.
contexts:
- context:  
    cluster: https://api.another1address
    namespace: name1           
    user: user1
    name: somename
- another_context: 
    cluster: https://api.anotheraddress
    namespace: esm2
    user: admin
    name: somename1`;
const doc = jsyaml.load(input);
console.log('servers: ' + doc.clusters.length);
doc.clusters.forEach(e => console.log('- ' + Object.keys(e)[0]));
console.log('namespaces: ' + doc.contexts.length);
doc.contexts.forEach(e => console.log('- ' + Object.keys(e)[0]));
</script>
</html>
```

Output:

```
servers: 2
- cluster
- second_cluster
namespaces: 2
- context
- another_context
```

Comment: here is the question with more information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71266575/how-to-use-a-js-yaml-parser-to-convert-yaml-like-file-content-into-json-using-re thanks