# How to use a js-yaml parser to convert yaml like file content into json using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript

I want to convert a file's content which is like `yaml` to `json`.

I have installed `js-yaml` library and have used the code below making an attempt to convert the file's content to `json`.

```
import fs from 'fs';
import yaml from 'js-yaml';

const useFile = (file) => {
    const [result, setResult] = React.useState<any>(null);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (!file) return;

        try {
            //let fileContents = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
            let result = yaml.load(file);
            setResult(result);
        } catch (e) {
            setError(e);
        }
    }, [file]);

    return { result, error };
};


const Parent = () => {
  
    const file = get(values, `${fieldRoot}.file`); 

    const handleUploadClick = React.useCallback(() => {
        if (inputRef && inputRef.current) {
            inputRef.current.click();
        }
    }, [inputRef]);

    const fileName = React.useMemo(() => {
        if (file) {
            return file.name;
        }
    }, [file]);

    return (
        <>
            <label> file </label>
            <input type="file" onchange={() => {
                const file = inputRef?.current?.files?.[0];
                if (file) {
                    try {
                        form.setFieldValue(`${fieldRoot}.file`, file);
                    } catch (error) {
                        notify({
                            status: 'error',
                            title: error.message,
                        });
                    }
                }
            )}
        />
        <button onclick={handleUploadClick}> upload</button>
    )}
```

When i upload the file i pass it to useFile hook to return the converted file to `json` using `js-yaml`

but the result is like this ["object File"]

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/492dO.png)

I am not sure what is wrong here. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Is that the whole code? can you give more details? label, textbox & button are not rendering...